# Propagate a DateTime column of a DataSet to database

Tags: c#, wpf, timestamp, sql-server-ce

I have a `DataSet` that has a timestamp (i.e. `Datetime.Now` ) recording the date and time when a row is added to the `DataSet` in memory. I will later save (or propagate) all these rows to the **SQLCE** database where the DataSet's timestamp will be propagate to a **DateTime** column in the database table.

It works fine and datetime comparison is also ok:

```
dataView1 = new DataView(
    dt,
    "DataTime >= '6/9/2011 5:00:20 PM'",
    "Data_ID ASC",
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

The above code works ok, but I worry if the program runs on different computer (i.e. another language of Windows) the `Datetime.Now` format would have a different format, or if I compare data that is record from a different computer, the different format of the DateTime in the database will causes it to fail. Would this problem happen? Or is there a safer way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String datetime = String.Format("{0:G}", ur_datetime_variable);
```

will give you string in `M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format and then convert the `datetime` string to `DateTime`

here's a link http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ and there's everything bout datetime formating.

Answer (score -1):

Should you not use CultureInvariant

DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo

when parsing dates